# CSS Stylesheet deletes itself after uploading to the server (ftp)

Tags: css, file, ftp, delete-file, uploading

The past half year I've had issues with my website. Sometimes when I upload my stylesheet.css file, using Transmit for my FTP (I work on a mac os) the file automatically removes itself from the server, leaving my website without CSS.

This problem happens inconsistently. The problem occurs 5-10 mins after uploading my stylesheet.css, but not always!

I've searched all over the web, but wasn't able to find a solution or anyone with my exact problem. I really hope someone has an answer for this problem, because whenever I upload my css file, my website might be left without a style.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first step is to look at server logs, I would imagine

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have looked at my log multiple times and all it shows me is that it handles a dele function. 

example: [09/Jan/2017:14:12:47 +0100] "DELE stylesheet.css"

Comment: there must be a stack trace as to what file is calling this command?

Comment: I can't find any file that calls this command, it just shows me the ip, function and date of the command.

Comment: Is it any file with the extension of '.css'? Are any other file extensions deleted?

Comment: No other files are deleted, it is specifically the stylesheet.css file. I've tried renaming the file, reuploading it while removing certain parts, but nothing seems to work.

It doesnt always happen, only sometimes and it's completely random.